# Flask-Admin: local variable 'admin' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I tried to add Flask-Admin into my project using Flask-Blueprint too, and then I ran into this problem

```
## UnboundLocalError: local variable 'admin' referenced before assignment ##
```

After I messed around I ran into another problem like

```
## A blueprint's name collision occurred … Both share the same name “admin” ##
```

but then I remove everything that has changed and I go back at the first problem!

- FlaskBackEnd/__ init __.py

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_mail import Mail
from FlaskBackEnd.config import Config
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView


db = SQLAlchemy()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'users.login'
login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'
mail = Mail()
admin = Admin(name='Admin', template_mode='bootstrap3')


def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    # initiate flask extentions
    db.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)
    admin.init_app(app)

    # Importing Blueprint packages
    from FlaskBackEnd.main.routes import main
    from FlaskBackEnd.posts.routes import posts
    from FlaskBackEnd.users.routes import users
    from FlaskBackEnd.errors.handler import errors
    from FlaskBackEnd.admin.routes import admin, user_datastore


    # Register blueprint app for ready to use
    app.register_blueprint(main)
    app.register_blueprint(posts)
    app.register_blueprint(users)
    app.register_blueprint(errors)
    app.register_blueprint(admin)

    return app
```

- FlaskBackEnd/admin/rountes.py

```py
from flask import render_template, Blueprint
from FlaskBackEnd.models import User, Post
from FlaskBackEnd import db, admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask_admin.contrib.fileadmin import FileAdmin
from wtforms.fields import PasswordField
import os.path as op

from flask_security import (current_user, login_required, RoleMixin, Security, 
                            SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, UserMixin, utils)

admin = Blueprint('admin', __name__)

admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(Post, db.session))

path = op.join(op.dirname(__file__), 'static')
admin.add_view(FileAdmin(path, '/static/img/', name='File Explore'))
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
app = create_app()
admin.init_app(app)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'admin' referenced before assignment

Comment: You are importing `admin` **after** using it.

Comment: Can you explain to me some more about it? I tried to fix around but it won't work

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you create the admin instance and bind it to the app in:

```py
from flask_admin import Admin

admin = Admin(name='Admin', template_mode='bootstrap3')
admin.init_app(app)
```

flask-admin already creates a blueprint on the fly and the blueprint will be named “admin”. That’s why you can’t add another customly created blueprint named “admin”. As you can see in [`flask_admin.base.Admin.init_app()`](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/3643d78808596f4634c8779e5decde9ef8ebda6e/flask_admin/base.py#L676)

So I’d suggest to:

- instantiate `flask_admin.Admin` in `routes/admin.py` and bind the views to it there.
- import the admin object in `__init__.py` and then only call `admin.init_app(self)` in the constructor.

This way you avoid creating two blueprints.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, I will try to work this out!

Comment: I forgot to say that I fixed the issue based on your suggestion. Thank you!